# Spring Boot, ReactJS - How to access secure API after login from Frontend React JS

Tags: reactjs, spring-security

I just start learning spring security. I searched for solution on how to access secure API from frontend based on user role after login but still no luck.

From the backend, I secure API by role like this.

- Only ADMIN role can access localhost:8080/admin/*
- Only USER role can access localhost:8080/user/*

Below is my WebSecureConfig.

```
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.cors().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/register","/add","/login","/index").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/*").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/*").hasAuthority("USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
            .failureUrl("/login?fail=true")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
}
```

This is my Entity class

```
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String username;
private String password;
private String role;
```

}

This is my controller class. I create 2 Get methods to test user role. One is admin url and one is user url

```
@GetMapping("/admin/index")
public String getAdminIndex(){
    return "This is Admin Page";
}

@GetMapping("/user/index")
public String getUserIndex(){
    return "This is User Page";
}
```

From frontend, I use axios to perform login

```
async login(_username, _password) {
return await axios.post(
  LOGIN_URL,
  {},
  {
    withCredentials: true,
    auth: {
      username: _username,
      password: _password,
    },
  }
);
```

}

It works. I got all information of user.
Then from frontend, I create 2 functions to handle get API based on role

```
getAdminPage() {
  return axios.get("http://localhost:8080/admin/index");
}
getUserPage() {
  return axios.get("http://localhost:8080/user/index");
```

}

[This is my login form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v8Rn.png)

On the login form, I have 2 buttons, Admin and User. Each button will handle a function getAdminPage() or getUserPage() which I mentioned above.

My question is, after login, only Admin role can click on Admin button, and only User role can click on User button. Even though both Admin and User roles can see both buttons. How can I handle that? Right now, I only know how to perform login, but do not know how to access secure API from frontend based on user role.

Thank you.

Comment: You should fetch what role the user has from the frontend and then display / send requests based on that. The actual security resides on the server, the frontend just needs to be aware of the permissions of the user, e.g. the role.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I just figure it out that I just need to put the basic authorization key or Json web token inside the header when call secure API,